# How to close UIView like "skype or any Window" minimize, in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview

I want to close UIView like the browser, skype and other window tab minimize. But I want to close my UIView like this. Means on which button I click my UIView close such as minize, and close where my button show ie: I put my UIButton on navigation.

I dont want to minimize my UIView, I want to close my UIView like its minimize.

Any hints from experts would be very welcome.

Comment: Experiment with animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];[UIView setAnimationDuration:<duration>];[UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:NO];[UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:0]
    [yourView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.009, 0.009)]; //if you dont get ratio start with 0.5,0.5 keep reducing till you get right number
  yourView.center=yourButton.center

[UIView commitAnimations]

//in order to maximize do

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];[UIView setAnimationDuration:<duration>];[UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:NO];[UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:0]
        [yourView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1)];
      yourView.center=CGPointMake(320/2.0f,480/2.0f);

    [UIView commitAnimations]
```

This should help you

Comment: Try this cmnt if need any thing

Comment: The code is working well now but this is not what I want. I want Minimize and close the view. This code moving the view horizontally, and stop where the button X-Position of button start. I want close my UIView like pagecurl style like minimize.

Comment: that will require some coding try researching ur self i will do it in spare time

Comment: Ok Thanks. I am also trying... And please if you find something please share with me also. Happy Coding...

Comment: what is ratiobetweenbuttonandview? what value I have to put in it?

Comment: transform will make your view small place the correct ratio between your view and button so that the scaled down view is of same dimensions as your button. try putting 0.5 to get general idea

Comment: Hey it is almost working, Please tell me what is ratiobetweenbuttonandview?  I am not able to put right value in it.

Comment: Ok it is minimizing but some part remaining before the button, I want all part of view hide inside exact where the button is placed. 5% remaining only.

Comment: 1*buttonWidth/viewWidth   similarly  1*buttonHeight/viewHeight   try reversing if it dosnt wrk

Comment: how to change this line and want to give my (x,y) coordinates of my UIView. so that I can control the view.

Comment: popup_View_under2.center=Pop_Hidebtn.center;

Comment: Take a look at @satish' lib

Comment: Amar how can I set Frame so That I can contorl my view and it will go and move according to me. Means I want to move my view (x,y)-> (320,0)

Comment: Ok Thanks aloot... Will try. Accpeting your answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14518853/uibutton-may-not-respond-to-enumerateobjectsusingblock-in-iphone