# UIButton may not respond to enumerateobjectsusingblock, in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I want to use BCGenieEffect in my app. I download demo example from github. https://github.com/Ciechan/BCGenieEffect

In this example xib is used and 4 UIButtons is used with xib. I want to use this code without xib and only for one button. I dont want to drag my view thats why I remove that code.

I have one UIButton:

```
UIButton *Pop_Hidebtn = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(290, 5, 15, 15)];
Pop_Hidebtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[Pop_Hidebtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"close.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Pop_Hidebtn.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
[Pop_Hidebtn addTarget:self action:@selector(Hidden_pop:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];  
[popup_View addSubview:Pop_Hidebtn];


-(void)Hidden_pop:(UIButton *)sender{
    [self genieToRect:sender.frame edge:BCRectEdgeBottom];
}


// I modified this and it says-> UIButton may not respond to enumerateobjectsusingblock
// And Crash 

- (void) genieToRect: (CGRect)rect edge: (BCRectEdge) edge {
    NSTimeInterval duration = 3.0;

    CGRect endRect = CGRectInset(rect, 5.0, 5.0);

    [help_Button enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIButton *button, NSUInteger idx, BOOL   *stop) { 
        help_Button.enabled = NO;
    }];


    if (self.viewIsIn) {

        [popup_View_under2 genieOutTransitionWithDuration:duration startRect:endRect      startEdge:edge completion:^{
            popup_View_under2.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

            [help_Button enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIButton *button, NSUInteger idx,  BOOL  *stop) {
                help_Button.enabled = YES;

            }];
        }];

    } else {
        popup_View_under2.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

        //UIButton may not respond to enumerateobjectsusingblock
        // Crash on this line
        [popup_View_under2 genieInTransitionWithDuration:duration destinationRect:endRect      destinationEdge:edge completion: ^{
            [help_Button enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIButton *button, NSUInteger idx,  BOOL *stop) {
                button.enabled = YES;
            }];
        }];
    }

    self.viewIsIn = ! self.viewIsIn;
}
```

how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:(void (^)(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop))block
```

Is an instance method of the `NSArray`, `NSOrderedSet` and `NSSet` classes. So it won't work if you call that method on what I assume is an instance of `UIButton`.

That method is intended to be used to enumerate objects in a collection. So you'd have to put your button in an `NSArray` (or `NSMutableArray`) in this way:

```
[myButtons enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIButton *aButton, NSUInteger idx, BOOL   *stop) { 
    aButton.enabled = NO;
}];
```

The block will be called for every object in the `myButtons` array, receiving the object itself (in this case, it will be casted to `UIButton *`), the index of said object, and a pointer to a `BOOL`, that you can use to exit the loop early.

Note that since you said you're going to use just one button, why don't you remove that methods call and just use

```
helpButton.enabled = YES;
```

without enumeration?

Comment: if I remove - (void)enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:(void (^)(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop))block and only use helpButton.enabled = YES; then the view is not minimizing.

Comment: how to write this line         [popup_View_under2 genieInTransitionWithDuration:duration destinationRect:endRect destinationEdge:edge completion:
if I remove or comment this line /* [popup_View_under2 genieInTransitionWithDuration:duration destinationRect:endRect destinationEdge:edge completion:
         ^{
             [help_Button enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIButton *button, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
                 button.enabled = YES;
             }];
         
         
         }];*/

Comment: `[popup_View_under2 genieInTransitionWithDuration:duration destinationRect:endRect destinationEdge:edge completion: ^{
helpButton.enabled = YES;
}]` should be ok.

Comment: not working, Sir could you please make one demo for fresher? It will help aloot for new developer. Beacuse its hard to tackle this problem for me. If you can please make a demo for us and share with me also. Thank You...